How to best convert an UTF-8 String to another Charset from StringBuilder?
I have a StringBuilder sb that contains prepared text, in UTF-8.
Question: which of the following approaches is better when converting to another charset like ISO8859-1:
Using a plain simple String:
new String(sb.toString().getBytes("ISO8859-1"), "ISO8859-1");
Or using ByteBuffer:
ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
CharBuffer data = Charset.forName("UTF-8").decode(inputBuffer);
new String(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1").encode(data).array(), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));

What are pros or cons that stand for one over the other approach (beside readability)?

String/StringBuilder always encodes their contents in either UTF-16 or Latin-1.  So the statement "I have a StringBuilder sb that contains prepared text, in UTF-8" does not make sense.

Okay sorry, then I probably ment UTF-16 as the default of StringBuilder, or better rephrase: I wanted to know how to convert the content from a StringBuilder (no matter which encoding) to Latin1. Is it possible to directly instantiate a StringBuilder in latin1?

@membersound: just as the "source" can not be UTF-8 in a StringBuilder, you also can't convert it to Latin1. It's always UTF-16. If you need data in another encoding, then you must be using ByteBuffer,byte[], InputStream, OutputStream. The entire family of String, StringBuilder, CharBuffer, char[], Reader and Writer only ever handles UTF-16 encoded text.

@JoachimSauer No, they aren't always in UTF-16. On current JVM releases, Strings are either in LATIN1 or UTF16-java-variant. Which one is used is an implementation detail that is not observable short of using reflection or profilers, and cannot be modified with code (or if it can, that'd be an implementation detail hack that has no bearing on anything except memory footprint; nothing in the string class acts differently depending on which internal representation is used by it). Somewhere before java.. 10? it was UTF-16-java-variant for all strings. That's quite a while ago.

That in itself is an implementation detail that's not visible to the user of the API. Java code  that interacts with String interacts with UTF-16 encoded data (outside of dirty reflective access). I see no reason to confuse people further by mentioning a detail that doesn't affect them 99.99% of the time. The fundamental understanding here is not about the details of the internal implementation of String but about the fundamental properties of the type in the language.


I have a StringBuilder sb that contains prepared text, in UTF-8.

You don't have that. That is not possible.
In java, strings (and StringBuilder, CharSequence, StringBuffer) contain text. They don't contain bytes, and don't have an encoding. In some languages, strings are sequences of bytes, or, are weakly typed in that sense (anywhere a sequence of bytes is needed, you can pass strings and vice versa). Java is not like that. A byte[] is one thing, a String is another, and they don't convert silently from one to the other.
As an implementation detail, a string's internal storage strategy depends on the characters in it and your JVM version - on modern versions, if all LATIN1 it's stored as LATIN1 and otherwise as a variant of UTF-16. You cannot modify this in any way, it is an implementation detail which is not possible to witness and is utterly irrelevant to how you write code.

new String(sb.toString().getBytes("ISO8859-1"), "ISO8859-1");


That's a silly way to waste time. This code does the same thing sb.toString() would do - the string object you end up with completely identical in every way, unless:

The stringbuilder contains characters that do not exist in ISO8859-1, in which case the above would throw an exception.
The above, naturally, wastes a bunch of time. Linear to the size of the input.

Your bytebuffer approach similarly does nothing other than waste a bunch of time and throw if a character isn't ISO8859-1 compatible. It has absolutely no effect whatsoever on that string.
It is not possible to have a java.lang.String object containing ISO8859-1.
When you say 'characters in UTF-8' you really mean 'bytes'. A stream of bytes can be in a charset encoding, in which case applying that charset encoding produces text. And, similarly, if you have text and you want bytes (which comes up a lot; if you want to send it over a pipe or save it to disk, those are all byte-based concepts), a charset encoding is used to do this conversion. So, if you have a need to specifically have 'characters in ISO8859-1', then your data type would be byte[], not String.
If all you're attempting to do is ensure that a bunch of strings that contain only ASCII take up no more than 1 byte per character, that already happens (starting in JDK11), automatically, regardless of how you make those strings. Even with UTF-8:
byte[] bytes = "Hello!".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String data = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Nevertheless ends up at a string that occupies 1 byte per character. You can't tell, no method in the String class tells you this stuff. You'd need memory profilers, and it might change in future versions of java. And String data = "Hello!"; would have had the same effect.

JEP 254: Compact Strings affected Java 9+. Is that the feature to which you refer?

Using a plain simple String:
Pros:

Simplicity: This approach is straightforward and easy to understand.
Compact: It’s a concise one-liner.

Cons:

Intermediate Byte Array: Internally, getBytes("ISO8859-1") creates an intermediate byte array, which can be less efficient in terms of memory usage.
Lossy Conversion: If any characters in the original UTF-8 text cannot be represented in ISO-8859-1, they will be replaced with replacement characters (usually ?).

Using ByteBuffer:
Pros:

Direct Conversion: This approach avoids creating an intermediate byte array. It directly converts from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 without an extra copy.
Fine-Grained Control: You can manipulate the ByteBuffer and CharBuffer directly if needed.

Cons:

Complexity: The code is more verbose and involves multiple steps.
Potential Bugs: Handling buffers correctly (flipping, clearing, etc.) can be error-prone.

Hope this helps you :)

question for both approaches: how can I ensure that I'm not losing unparsable characters, but can an exception in that case?

java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder javadocs will show you various options for unmappable characters. Having said that, I'm not sure what your motivation for this encoding activity is...
